# Trying to change bot's status

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I got this script that should work, the script below is meant to change the bot's status to idle, But when i say the command it just says `Bot is online` which it's meant to say after bot is actually idle. This works in JDA java, in java you can turn bot to offline, idle, DND and it works so I was just wondering is this just not available for python or something?

I've already search the internet for this but what i get all doesn't work

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def idle(ctx, *,text):
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name=text),
                                 status=discord.Status('idle'),
                                 afk=True)
    await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'Bot is Idle')
```

I expect the bot to become idle.

Answer (score 0):

**Never mind, i just had to wait for along time!** But after that the next time it was working quick. *Confusing!*